# Can't create javascript XPCOM service for Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I've been banging my head a against this particular brick wall now for more than two days.  I am attempting to create an XPCOM service for use in a Firefox extension but am unable to initialise the component with the following error displayed in the error console in Firefox.

```
Timestamp: 07/06/2012 09:23:28 Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... 
"Component returned failure code: 0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE)
[nsIJSCID.getService]"  nsresult: "0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE)"
location: "JS frame :: chrome://logger/content/logger.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 21"
data: no]
```

I have reduced the component to the bare minimum using the excellent boilerplate generator at [ted.mielczarek.org](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/jscomponentwiz/).  The component code is as follows...

```
const nsISupports = Components.interfaces.nsISupports;
const CLASS_ID = Components.ID("808e1607-caea-418c-b563-d9fe1df6ee08");
const CLASS_NAME = "Test component";
const CONTRACT_ID = "@test/loggerservice;1";

function LoggerService() {
  this.wrappedJSObject = this;
}

LoggerService.prototype = {
  QueryInterface: function(aIID)
  {
    if (!aIID.equals(nsISupports))
      throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
    return this;
  }
}
```

The remainder of the boilerplate that creates the module and factory interfaces is unchanged.

The chrome.manifest file looks like this...

```
content   logger                 chrome/content/
skin      logger   classic/1.0   chrome/skin/
locale    logger   en-US         chrome/locale/en-US/

component {808e1607-caea-418c-b563-d9fe1df6ee08} components/loggerservice.js
contract @test/loggerservice;1 {808e1607-caea-418c-b563-d9fe1df6ee08}

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://logger/content/logger-overlay.xul
style   chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://logger/skin/overlay.css
```

Finally, the `logger-overlay.xul` file includes a script file - `logger.js` - which attempts to get a reference to the `LoggerService` component using the following code...

```
this.loggerService = Components.classes["@test/logger;1"].getService().wrappedJSObject;
```

and it is this line that is reporting in the firefox error console.

I can't see how much simpler I can make it - any insight would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice boilerplate generator but unfortunately an outdated one. For one, you should be using [XPCOMUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm), this will get rid of most of the boilerplate. More importantly, this boilerplace generator hasn't been updated to [XPCOM changes in Gecko 2.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#JavaScript_components) and defines `NSGetModule` function instead of `NSGetFactory`. Module code like this should work however:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

function LoggerService() {
  this.wrappedJSObject = this;
}

LoggerService.prototype = {
  classID: Components.ID("808e1607-caea-418c-b563-d9fe1df6ee08"),
  classDescription: "Test component",
  contractID: "@test/loggerservice;1",

  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([])
}

if ("generateNSGetFactory" in XPCOMUtils)
  var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([LoggerService]);  // 2.0+
else
  var NSGetModule = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetModule([LoggerService]);    // 1.9.x
```

You can remove the `NSGetModule` code if your extension doesn't need to be compatible with Firefox 3.6. You can also remove the `classDescription` and `contractID` properties then, these are specified in `chrome.manifest` already.

*Note*: If you only need an object that will stay around for the entire browsing session and can be accessed from anywhere then a [JavaScript code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using) would be a better choice - no XPCOM boilerplate and no `wrappedJSObject` hacks.

Comment: Wladimir - thanks - top advice!  The code is so much cleaner now as well with the use of XPCOMUtils.  At last I can now get on and develop my service!