# Using a javascript XPCOM component to create a custom autocomplete box in a FireFox add-on

Tags: autocomplete, firefox-addon, custom-component, xpcom

I've spent a few days reading over all manner of [tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript/), [MDN entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/XPCOM_Interfaces), and [S.O. posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928864/cant-create-javascript-xpcom-service-for-firefox-extension), and I've come to suspect that I'm missing something obvious, but I'm too inexperienced with XPCOM to spot it. I'm about 80% sure there error is somewhere in my custom component (components/fooLogin.js).

**Problem:** When the add-on initializes (when I call loadData() from chrome/content/foologin.js), I get an error saying:

> TypeError: Components.classes['@foo.com/foologinautocomplete;1'] is undefined

Am I maybe trying to create the component before the class has been registered? Is there something else I need to do to register it? Any tips would be appreciated.

**Relevant Code:** (happy to supply any additional code, if need be)

components/fooLogin.js:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
function fooLoginAutoComplete(){
        this.wrappedJSObject = this;
}
fooLoginAutoComplete.prototype = {
        classID: Components.ID("loginac@foo.com"),
        contractID: "@foo.com/foologinautocomplete;1",
        classDescription: "Auto complete for foo",
        QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([]),
        complete: function(str){  // Autocomplete functionality will in this function
                return null;
        }
};
var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([fooLoginAutoComplete]);
```

chrome/content/foologin.js:

```
let fooLogin = {
    dataLoaded : false,
    searchFilter = null,
    ...
    loadData : function(){
        ...
        try{
            alert(1);  // This alert fires
            this.searchFilter = Components.classes['@foo.com/foologinautocomplete;1']
                .getService().wrappedJSObject;
            alert(2);  // I get the error before this alert
        }catch(e){alert(e);}
        this.dataLoaded = true;
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    if(!fooLogin.dataLoaded) fooLogin.loadData();
}
```

chrome.manifest:

```
content foologin         chrome/content/
content foologin         chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes
skin    foologin classic chrome/skin/
locale  foologin en-US   chrome/locale/en-US/

component loginac@foo.com                 components/fooLogin.js
contract  @foo.com/foologinautocomplete;1 loginac@foo.com

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://foologin/content/foologin.xul
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your chrome.manifest, you have this:

> component loginac@foo.com                 components/fooLogin.js
>   contract  @foo.com/foologinautocomplete;1 loginac@foo.com

and in fooLogin.js you have:

> classID: Components.ID("loginac@foo.com"),

loginac@foo.com is not a valid class ID for a component.

They have to be of the form:

{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Only add-ons can have a foo@bar.com format.

Comment: Spot on! That was exactly my problem. The docs are a little unclear on that point. They should explicitly say that ONLY add-ons can use the loose format (or maybe they do and I missed it). Anyway, thanks for the tip!

For anyone else who may need it, here's a handy [online GUID generator](http://www.somacon.com/p113.php).

Cheers